# Implement direct calling from Android App

Tags: android

I want to make calls from my app when the user clicks on a button but when the button is click for the first time, the permission dialog box pops up, but after granting the permission the call is not activated with the start activity.Please help me out

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText et;
Button call_btn;
Context context;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    call_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    call_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + et.getText().toString()));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch (SecurityException e){
                    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                    String s = writer.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else {
                getPermission();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void getPermission(){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
    } else {

    }
}
```

}

Below is what I have in my manifest.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="flashcodesolution.recharger">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the onRequestPermissionsResult method and make call again like below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + et.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, if you just want to open the built-in Phone app, you can change the action to Intent.ACTION_DIAL which requires no permissions.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to hear that.